# Active Directory computers not contain certain group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group, group-membership

I have to audit whole Active Directory domain computers with software.
I find out that old admin deployed Audit software for Group 'Audit_Software'.
My goal is find all computers in domain which dont have 'Audit_Software' membership.

eg. 'Audit_Software' contain 2x computer accounts
'netbios_PC1'
'netbios_PC2'

but whole domain have many more computer accounts without that group.
How to use powershell to find computer accounts in AD (all containers) without 'Audit_Software' group ??

Comment: You need to tell what you have tried, what didn't work, and specifically _how_ it didn't work (i.e., precise error messages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate the members of that group like this:

```
$group = Get-ADGroup -Identity 'Audit_Software'
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | select -Expand Name
```

then enumerate all computers and filter for those whose name is *not* in that list:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | ? { $members -notcontains $_.Name }
```